# Which shloka of which mandala of Rigveda - are part of Rigvedic "samhita"?

Tags: vedas, samhita

As every veda has four parts.

Which shloka of which mandala of Rigveda - are part of  Rigvedic **"samhita"** ? Is there any list available?

which list of shloka/mandala are part of **rigveda brahmana**

which list of shloka/mandala are part of **rigveda aranyak**

which list of shloka/mandala are part of **rigveda's end upanishadik part**

Comment: Do you mean Index? All  mantras from all the 10 mandalas are part of Rig-Veda samhita.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar: i edited my question to make it more clear

Comment: Rigveda Samhita is made of 10 Mandalas. So, all the Shlokas of all 10 Mandalas are part of Rigveda Samhitas.

Comment: then where is rigveda brahmana and where is rigveda aranyak? can you provide some link to resource?